# Is there a way to achieve fast access to the root directory in a url?

Tags: directory

You can access the parent directory by using "../" in a url, so if I have a file system that looks like this:

root -> branch -> leaf

and I am in the leaf directory, I can access the root directory by using the url: "../../"

Is there a way to access root directly without using a bunch of "../" in my urls?

Comment: You can use only `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a short answer, simply use `/`